# Authorization of Azure Storage service REST API

Tags: javascript, azure-storage

I've been stuck for the whole day making my first call of Azure Storage REST API. Postman's response showed that it's due to error in Azure authentication, but I have no idea what's the problem.

Here is the browser script to send Azure Storage REST API:

```
function azureListContainers() {

var key = "key-copied-from-azure-storage-account";
var strTime = (new Date()).toUTCString();
var strToSign = 'GET\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:' + strTime + '\nx-ms-version:2015-12-11\n/myaccount/?comp=list';

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, key);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = "SharedKeyLite myaccount:"+hashInBase64;

console.log(strToSign);
console.log(auth);
console.log(strTime);

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
        request.setRequestHeader("x-ms-date", strTime);
        request.setRequestHeader("x-ms-version", "2015-12-11");
    },
    url: "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list",
    processData: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
}
```

Chrome Developer Tool just returned No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header without further reason, so I copied the contents of `var auth` and `var strTime`, created the same request using Postman tool:

```
[Command]
GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list


[Headers]
Authorization:SharedKeyLite myaccount:Z9/kY/D+osJHHz3is+8yJRqhj09VUlr5n+PlePUa8Lk=
x-ms-date:Tue, 09 Aug 2016 10:30:49 GMT
x-ms-version:2015-12-11


[Response Body]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:9be3d595-0001-0012-4929-f2fde2000000
Time:2016-08-09T10:31:52.6542965Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'Z9/kY/D+osJHHz3is+8yJRqhj09VUlr5n+PlePUa8Lk=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET



x-ms-date:Tue, 09 Aug 2016 10:30:49 GMT
x-ms-version:2015-12-11
/myaccount/?comp=list'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

After diff the two strings, I believe `var strToSign` in my script is the same as the string Azure used to sign. But still there was an authentication error. Please help indicate what's the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Chrome Developer Tool just returned No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

As you are using javascript to send http requests against to Azure Storage Server directly from client. It's a common [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue.

When you occur this issue, you can [enable the CORS for your storage services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx#Anchor_1). For simple, you can leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to configure your storage.

[image]

> AuthenticationFailed

I did two modifications based on your code snippet, in my test project to make it work.

1. `var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, key);` The second parameter, should be a base64 decode from the account key, refer to the [Azure Storage SDK for node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/common/signing/hmacsha256sign.js#L27)
2. In my test, I had to use `SharedKey` scheme and authenticate with `SharedKey` token to make your scenario to work.

Here is my test code snippet, FYI.,

```
var key = "key-copied-from-azure-storage-account";
var strTime = (new Date()).toUTCString();
var strToSign = 'GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:' + strTime + '\nx-ms-version:2015-12-11\n/<accountname>/\ncomp:list';
var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = "SharedKey <accountname>:"+hashInBase64;
```

Additionally, for security reason, please implement the Azure Storage Services in backend web server. As using pure javascript on client, will expose your account name and account key to public, which will raise the risk to your data and info.

Comment: Thank you for saving my life, Gary ! As a noob and came directly from [this Authentication doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx) I didn't know it's necessary to base64 decode the key first. If possible please add a sample code snippet in the doc for others to quick start.  :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: This seems to be working for blob, but not for Table.