# How to upload media file in the blob storage of Azure Media Services using Rest API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I am accessing Azure Media Rest API using javascript (angular js), I followed the Microsoft documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-get-started) through which I was able to generate the token, connect to media services, create the access token and the locator. But after this step, I am facing a problem in uploading a file into a blob storage container.
Is there any way to perform uploading of a file via client side using Angular js or javascript?

while making a request:-
PUT https:/storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/assetcontainer/filename?sas token HTTP/1.1
Host: storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 223
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Origin: http://localhost
Authorization : SharedKey accountnamw: access key
Content-Type: video/mp4
Accept: application/json, 
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18

This gives a response :-
HTTP/1.1 400 Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.
Content-Length: 297
Content-Type: application/xml
x-ms-request-id: e6b8eeaa-0001-003e-4403-6958b9000000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Sat, 07 Jan 2017 16:34:38 GMT

On trying to remove authorization header and date header from the request, the response we receive is a 404 error: resource does not exist. I am looking for a proper solution to upload file to the blob storage container, kindly help me in resolving this issue .

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Since uploading is not something that is handled by the Media Services API itself, you would need to look for examples of using the Azure Storage APIs to upload into a Block Blob via a SAS URL.

Since you have a writable Locator (SAS URL) already, you now need to write to the block blob.

I've seen some examples of doing this out there on the web from client side Angular code.  For example - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2015/12/18/securely-upload-to-azure-storage-with-angular/

I'll check to see if we have any more examples

Comment: While making a request which looks like :-

Comment: PUT storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/asset/… HTTP/1.1 Host: storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net ,Connection: keep-alive, x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob, Authorization : SharedKey myaccount: "key" ,Content-Type: video/mp4, Accept: application/json, x-ms-version: 2011-08-18 x-ms-date: Sat, 07 Jan 2017 16:07:36 GMT

Comment: response: HTTP/1.1 400 Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.           Content-Length: 297                                                                         Content-Type: application/xml                                                            Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 x-ms-request-id: --------                 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost                                                Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true Date: Sat, 07 Jan 2017 16:34:38 GMT

Comment: And when we remove the Authorization header, date header from the request, the response we receive is 404:the specified resource does not exist. Can you guide me the way to step out of this issue .

Comment: Hi,@MohitNautiyal, according your comment timeline, at last you have solved your issue? If you still have any concerns, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is not an existing Azure storage SDK for javascript in client side using. So we can manually generate SAS token URLs fro uploading blobs from client applications.

You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1 for the detailed guidance.

Also, you can refer this thread [Authorization of Azure Storage service REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849384/authorization-of-azure-storage-service-rest-api/38865101#38865101) as we discussed how to generate SAS token in javascript on client side previous.

Comment: This issue is taking a lot of efforts to clear and still we are facing some or other problem again and again .

Comment: PUT https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/asset/filename?sastoken HTTP/1.1
Host: storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net
Connection: keep-alive
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob

Authorization : SharedKey myaccount: "key"
Content-Type: video/mp4
Accept: application/json,
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18
x-ms-date: Sat, 07 Jan 2017 16:07:36 GMT....

Comment: response:  HTTP/1.1 400 Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.
Content-Length: 297
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: --------
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Sat, 07 Jan 2017 16:34:38 GMT

Comment: And when we remove the Authorization header, date header from the request, the response we receive is 404:the specified resource does not exist. Can you guide me the way  to step out of this issue