# How to upload images using postman to azure blob storage

Tags: azure, rest, blob, azure-blob-storage, binaryfiles

I have been trying to upload an image to my blob container folder using postman
Here is the link [Authorization of Azure Storage service REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849384/authorization-of-azure-storage-service-rest-api) am using to generate signature and am attaching filename file field in the body while body.

```
var key = "[Storage account key]";
var strTime = (new Date()).toUTCString();
var strToSign = 'PUT\n\nimage/jpeg; charset=UTF-8\n\nx-ms-date:' + strTime + '\nx-ms-meta-m1:v1\nx-ms-meta-m2:v2\n/colony7/folder-customer-profilepic/Home - explorar.jpg';
var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = "SharedKey colony7:"+hashInBase64;
```

I have used these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block ,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services
references for above code.

I have turned on cors also. Kindly share the solution as to how would i upload a jpg or png image to my blob using postman.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does not directly answer your question but have you tried Azure Storage Explorer? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/features/storage-explorer/

Comment: Why did you tag this with S3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we want to upload an image to the azure storage, please have a try to use the [Put blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob)  API **not** [Put block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) API.

And have a try to use the following strToSign.

```
"PUT\n\n\n{Content-Length}\n\n{Content-Type}\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:{date}\nx-ms-version:2015-12-11\n/accountname/container/blobname"
```

I test it on my side, it works correctly on site.

**Headers :**

[image]

Body:

[image]

Note: we could get the Content-Length from the file size.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way i can upload without using content length header as it is restricted ?

Comment: how do i send binary png file via ajax request to azure, When i tried to send data it was sending 0bytes of data

Comment: `Is there a way i can upload without using content length header as it is restricted ` According to  [Put blob API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob), the `Content-Length` header is required.

Comment: `how do i send binary png file via ajax request to azure, When i tried to send data it was sending 0bytes of data`  Please have a try to create a new thread, as it is another question. Please also supply more info such as demo code, error info and screenshot etc. in another thread.

Answer (score 5):

1. Method: `PUT`.
2. URL scheme:

   ```
   (https://{{storageName}}.blob.core.windows.net/{{Container}}/{{ImageName.png}}?{{SAS Token}})
   ```
3. Headers:

   ```
   "Content-Type": "image/png",
   "Content-Length": "{{size in Bytes}}",
   "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob"
   ```
4. Body: select binary add image
   (The image name should be same in the header and the URL.)

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer to your question, but I see a number of issues that could cause this problem you're facing. Some of the issues I noticed are:

1. Request URL does not include the name of the file you're uploading. Your request URL should be `https://colony7.blob.core.windows.net/folder-customer-profilepic/Home - explorar.jpg`.
2. Content type request header is sent as `image/jpg`. However, in your `stringToSign` it is set as `image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8`. Both of them should exactly match.
3. Content length header is missing in `stringToSign`.
4. Based on the documentation here, your `stringToSign` corresponds to `SharedKeyLite` however when creating the authorization header, you are using `SharedKey`.
5. Your `CanonicalizedHeaders` does not include `x-ms-version`.
6. If you intend to use `SharedKey`, then your `stringToSign` should be constructed differently. Please see the documentation link you shared for more details.

Please fix these errors and update your question with the latest screenshots/values.