# Upload file to OneDrive from a Java Application

Tags: java, sharepoint, upload, onedrive

I'm trying to use a Java application to upload a file to OneDrive and am somewhat struggling with the process. I think my main issue is that I don't quite get the Drives and Folders concept as Microsoft defines them. And so am unable to see what the URL should be to upload to.

For now I would be ecstatic just to upload a file to my own OneDrive folder that I see whenever I log into my company's "Sharepoint" site. So this would not be a personal OneDrive upload. 
Eventually though I will need to be able to construct a URL that points to whatever folder that the requirements call for to deposit the file.

Scouring the WEB (and Stackoverflow) I have found people specifying 2 different types of URLs to upload a file to.

1. https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token="+sAccessToken - This first one appears to be a MS URL that is somehow supposed to figure out what my folder is.
2. https://mycompanyname.sharepoint.com/me/drive?access_token="+sAccessToken - This one is specific to my company. And in my mind points to my default directory. But for the life of me I cannot get it to work. Even in Chrome Postman let alone in my Java application.

I consistently get either a 401 or 404 error. Now 401 is an authorization error so do I think it's a URL issue. Well, because I created the application and gave the ReadWrite rights that myself. And I used the secret from this application to obtain the AccessKey which does work.
So my guess is that I am accessing an incorrect folder, i.e. not mine but someone else's and as a result am getting the 401 message.

I'm not posing the Java code since I can't even get this to work in Postman. So if I left anything out please let me know.

Thank you to all in advance

Comment: Were you able to find the solution ? I have similar kind of requirement and I am also looking for the solution. Please suggest if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [One Drive API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content), one can upload files to One Drive personal using following 3 approaches:

- **Simple Upload:** (Of course with some limitation on size of the file to be uploaded)

  We only need to pass the file name with extension as path parameter in url and the actual file in body as binary attachment.

[image: file name with extension as a path parameter]
[image: request body as a binary attachment]

And you are done with simple upload.

***Note:** You can mention an id of a particular directory instead of "root" in the url, if you want to upload file to directory other than Root Directory.*

- **Multipart Upload:** (This strategy also has a size limitation on a file to be uploaded) One should go for this approach only when file content + file metadata is to be uploaded in a single api call.

[image: Request url and headers for multipart upload on One Drive]

[image: Request body payload for multipart upload on One Drive]

This didn't work for me as the base 64 encoded payload gets uploaded without being decoded at one drive server, the uploaded file is not previewable. Seems like one drive is ignoring the Content-Encoding-Scheme header (probably a bug) or this is not supported at all. :(

Please let me know if you could able to fix it.

The content in payload is getting uplaoded properly but as it ignoring the content encoding scheme for media files,
the content is getting uplaoded as base 64 encoded content which is not previewable in one drive.

Follow below links to know more on this issue:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902003/multipart-upload-binary-content-with-onedrive-rest-apis)

[Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odwork-odfiles-sdweb/trouble-uploading-image-with-multipart-upload/44c5b834-a826-46b2-8820-c233d2fa2bae)

- **Session Upload (For large files):** Here you need to create an upload session and then upload data to the created session in chunks. For more details follow this link [Session Upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession).

[image: Creating upload session]

[image: Uploading data to created session in chunks]

and attach file as binary attachment.

This was all for POSTMAN client.

If you wish to upload the same with java code here is sample code that might help:
[Sample upload application](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-example/)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    File convertFile = new File("FileDirectoryPath"+file.getOriginalFilename());
    //convertFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convertFile);
    fos.write(file.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    return new ResponseEntity<>("file uploaded successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```