# Authorization of Azure Storage service REST API for table

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

i've been stuck for the whole day making my call of Azure Storage REST API. response showed that it's due to error in Azure authentication, but I have no idea what's the problem.
you can check the similar problem here also

[Authorization of Azure Storage service REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849384/authorization-of-azure-storage-service-rest-api)

by using this i got the blod worked for me but not for the table.
how to achieve this with the table

```
var apiVersion = '2017-07-29';
var storageAccountName = "MyAccountName";
var key = "MyAccountKey";

var currentDate= new Date();
var strTime = currentDate.toUTCString();
var strToSign = 'GET\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:' + strTime + '\nx-ms-version:' + apiVersion + '\n/' + storageAccountName + '/?restype=service&comp=properties';
var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccountName + ":" + hashInBase64; 
document.write(auth)
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://MyAccountName.table.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties&sv=2017-07-29&ss=bqtf&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup",
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
        request.setRequestHeader("x-ms-date", strTime);
        request.setRequestHeader("x-ms-version", apiVersion);
    },
    processData: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        // Do something
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle error
    }
});
```

Above snippet is to access Azure table storage. However this is not working. But if I try this against blob, it seems to be working

```
var strToSign = 'GET\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:' + strTime + '\nx-ms-version:' + apiVersion + '\n/' + storageAccountName + '/?comp=list';
url: "https://appcrestdev.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list",
```

Comment: Issue is similar to what is posted in the link, but for "Table" storage.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: As Gaurav said, please share your code so others can help you. In addition, why not use Azure Storage Client Library directly rather than write your own authentication code?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 1):

`strToSign` for table authentication is different from that for blob.

You can change two variables as below and have a try, it works on my side.

`var strToSign = strTime + '\n/' + storageAccountName + '/?comp=properties';`

`url: "https://MyAccountName.table.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties"`

And here's some references for you.

- [get-table-service-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-table-service-properties)
- [authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services#Subheading2)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the following tutorial for authentication to see if you've missed a step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujzrq8Fg9Gc
This should resolve your issues.

This is the link to the REST API for Azure services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad