# I am getting an authentication error while updating data in Azure table storage using SharedKeyLite in NodeJS code

Tags: node.js, azure-table-storage

I am trying to update Azure Table storage using Rest API and SharedKeyLite in my nodejs code but getting authentication error -
*"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."*

Please find my nodejs code below-

```
const Request = require('request');
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

let apiVersion = '2018-03-28';
let contentType = 'application/json';
let dataServiceVersion = '3.0;NetFx';
let maxDataServiceVersion = '3.0;NetFx';
let storageAccountName = "mybotstorage";
let tableName = "myBotCounter";
let key = "**********************YO+MnTwBBbKKcPfsFQwg==";

var strTime = (new Date()).toUTCString();
let strToSign = strTime + '\n/' + storageAccountName + '/' + tableName + '(PartitionKey=\'mypartkey\',RowKey=\'myrowkey\')';
var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = "SharedKeyLite mybotstorage:" + hashInBase64;

var postData = {
    "counter": "1050"
}

let content = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(postData));
let contentLength = content.byteLength;

let headers = {};
headers['Authorization'] = auth;
headers['x-ms-date'] = strTime;
headers['x-ms-version'] = apiVersion;
headers['DataServiceVersion'] = dataServiceVersion;
headers['MaxDataServiceVersion'] = maxDataServiceVersion;
headers['Content-Type'] = contentType;
headers["Content-Length"] = contentLength;
headers["Accept-Charset"] = "UTF-8";
headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

let url = "https://mybotstorage.table.core.windows.net/" + tableName + "(PartitionKey='mypartky',RowKey='myrowkey')";
var options = {
    headers: headers,
    method: 'PUT',
    body: content,
    url: url
}
Request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error posting json: ', err)
        throw err
    }
    var headers = res.headers;
    var statusCode = res.statusCode;
    console.log('headers: ', headers);
    console.log('statusCode: ', statusCode);
    console.log('body: ', body);
});
```

Note : Retrieving data with 'GET' and inserting data with 'POST' works fine using nodejs, only I am not able to update data with 'PUT' method in nodejs.

Also I tested 'PUT' method using C# code, it works fine but nodejs code gives an authentication error.

Comment: Can you check if adding CORS for PUT request helps you, for reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849384/authorization-of-azure-storage-service-rest-api
Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes Mohit, I have already added CORS for PUT request for Table service, but still its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to encoding of url which is handled differently by C# and NodeJS.
I am posting the working code sample for reference.

```
const Request = require('request');
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

let apiVersion = '2013-08-15';
let contentType = 'application/json';
let storageAccountName = "mybotstorage";
let tableName = "myBotCounter";
let key = "*******************************YO+MnTwBBbKKcPfsFQwg==";

let strTime = (new Date()).toUTCString();
let strToSign = strTime + '\n/' + storageAccountName + '/' + tableName + '(PartitionKey=%27mypartitionkey%27,RowKey=%27myrowkey%27)';
let secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
let hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
let hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
let auth = "SharedKeyLite mybotstorage:" + hashInBase64;
console.log(strToSign);
console.log(auth);

let postData = {
    "counter": "1088"
}
let headers = {};
headers['Content-Type'] = contentType;
headers['Authorization'] = auth;
headers['x-ms-date'] = strTime;
headers['x-ms-version'] = apiVersion;

let url = "https://mybotstorage.table.core.windows.net/" + tableName + "(PartitionKey=%27mypartitionkey%27,RowKey=%27myrowkey%27)";
console.log('url------', url);
var options = {
    headers: headers,
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(postData),
    url: url
}
Request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error posting json: ', err)
        throw err
    }
    var headers = res.headers;
    var statusCode = res.statusCode;
    console.log('headers: ', headers);
    console.log('statusCode: ', statusCode);
    console.log('body: ', body);
});
```